# How to profile the App uses in Android?

Tags: android, profiling, root

I want to collect App activation sequence in an Android system.

E.g.

If a user first open Youtube App, then switch to Gmail App, then switch back to Youtube App and so on, then the sequence is like:

```
Youtube Gmail Youtube ...
```

Is there available App existing in Google Play or somewhere else to achieve this?

Is it straightforward to implement? Is it possible to achieve the goal with pure App solution?

Is it require rooting the device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to poll this function on some regular interval.
You can further write a logic to remove subsequently duplicate Application Label.

```
private string getActiveApplicationLabel(){
  String appLabel = null;
  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
  Iterator i = l.iterator();
  PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
  while(i.hasNext()) {
  ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());

  try {
    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName,  
     PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
     appLabel = c.toString();
    }catch(Exception e) {
      //Name Not FOund Exception
    }

 }
 return appLabel;
}
```